# How magento schedule update for magento product programmatically?

Tags: magento2, event-observer, schedule

How i magento perform schedule update programmatically.

1. which module i check, how magento perform schedule update ?
2. please narrate which file work ?

Answer (score 0):

Magento manage its schedule joob via cronjob.

If you will create a custom module and define that your code will run in the schedule then you need to add your code to Magento cron job

Please follow the below article for how you can define a custom cronjob for the requirement:

- https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/config-guide/cron/custom-cron-ref.html
- https://www.mageplaza.com/devdocs/magento-2-create-cron-job/#create-crontabxml
- https://magefan.com/blog/create-custom-cron-job-in-magento-2
- https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/config-guide/cli/config-cli-subcommands-cron.html

See below example:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Cron:etc/crontab.xsd">
    <group id="default">
        <job name="vendorname_modulename_cron_somecronmodel" instance="VendorName\ModuleName\Cron\Cronfile" method="execute">
            <schedule>* * * * *</schedule>
        </job>
     </group>
</config>
```

As per our requirement, you need to write your product update code to VendorName\ModuleName\Cron\Cronfile.php